# in query mysql with column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column that have data value `49,22`
Now running below query. it is not returning any result.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 22 IN column_name
```

what could be problem?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a bad DB design and you should never store comma-separated values, and normalize the table, however in this case you need to use `find_in_set` function as

```
select * FROM `tablename`
where find_in_set(22,column_name) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check multiple rows if they contain `22` or `49`, you can use the `IN` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE column_name IN(22,49)
```

If you just want to check if `22` is in a string which is `49,22` then use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE column_name LIKE '%22%'
```

Your question is in this point a bit unclear. :-)